# How to compare each first index of multidimensional array and to push into another array if they are the same

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm going to go into more detail.

Say I have an array like this:

JSON version of the array:

```
[
    {
        "SKU": "COL-10-49000 ",
        "SHOP": "GWUK ",
        "FLDDEF": "Body_HTML ",
        "PARB": " ",
        "STAT1": "U ",
        "FREIA1": " ",
        "FREIA2": " "
    },
    {
        "SKU": "COL-10-49000 ",
        "SHOP": "GWUK ",
        "FLDDEF": "Metafield_3 ",
        "PARB": "icon_image_2 ",
        "STAT1": "U ",
        "FREIA1": "19000726159421 ",
        "FREIA2": " "
    },
    {
        "SKU": "COL-10-49310 ",
        "SHOP": "GWIN ",
        "FLDDEF": "SEO_1 ",
        "PARB": "title_tag ",
        "STAT1": "U ",
        "FREIA1": "19034707656748 ",
        "FREIA2": " "
    },
    {
        "SKU": "COL-10-49000 ",
        "SHOP": "GWIN ",
        "FLDDEF": "Metafield_14 ",
        "PARB": "subtitle ",
        "STAT1": " ",
        "FREIA1": "19472915890220 ",
        "FREIA2": " "
    },
    {
        "SKU": "COL-10-49000 ",
        "SHOP": "GWEUEN ",
        "FLDDEF": "Metafield_9 ",
        "PARB": "icon_label_1 ",
        "STAT1": " ",
        "FREIA1": "20117934276662 ",
        "FREIA2": " "
    },
    {
        "SKU": "COL-10-49000 ",
        "SHOP": "GWEUDE ",
        "FLDDEF": "Metafield_14 ",
        "PARB": "icon_label_3 ",
        "STAT1": "U ",
        "FREIA1": "13660255911996 ",
        "FREIA2": " "
    },
    {
        "SKU": "COL-10-49000 ",
        "SHOP": "GWIN ",
        "FLDDEF": "Body_HTML ",
        "PARB": " ",
        "STAT1": " ",
        "FREIA1": " ",
        "FREIA2": " "
    },
    {
        "SKU": "COL-10-49310 ",
        "SHOP": "GWEUDE ",
        "FLDDEF": "Metafield_3 ",
        "PARB": "image ",
        "STAT1": "U ",
        "FREIA1": "13675072946236 ",
        "FREIA2": " "
    },
    {
        "SKU": "COL-10-49309 ",
        "SHOP": "GWUK ",
        "FLDDEF": "Collection_Title ",
        "PARB": " ",
        "STAT1": "U ",
        "FREIA1": " ",
        "FREIA2": " "
    },
    {
        "SKU": "COL-10-49309 ",
        "SHOP": "GWEUFR ",
        "FLDDEF": "Metafield_2 ",
        "PARB": "icon ",
        "STAT1": "U ",
        "FREIA1": "18980910989369 ",
        "FREIA2": " "
    },
    {
        "SKU": "COL-10-49310 ",
        "SHOP": "GWEUDE ",
        "FLDDEF": "Collection_Title ",
        "PARB": " ",
        "STAT1": "U ",
        "FREIA1": " ",
        "FREIA2": " "
    },
    {
        "SKU": "COL-10-49000 ",
        "SHOP": "GWEUEN ",
        "FLDDEF": "Metafield_7 ",
        "PARB": "subtitle ",
        "STAT1": " ",
        "FREIA1": "20117934211126 ",
        "FREIA2": " "
    },
    {
        "SKU": "COL-10-49310 ",
        "SHOP": "GWEUDE ",
        "FLDDEF": "Handle ",
        "PARB": " ",
        "STAT1": "U ",
        "FREIA1": "166926024764 ",
        "FREIA2": " "
    },
    {
        "SKU": "COL-10-49000 ",
        "SHOP": "GWEUEN ",
        "FLDDEF": "Body_HTML ",
        "PARB": " ",
        "STAT1": " ",
        "FREIA1": " ",
        "FREIA2": " "
    },
    {
        "SKU": "COL-10-49310 ",
        "SHOP": "GWEUFR ",
        "FLDDEF": "Body_HTML ",
        "PARB": " ",
        "STAT1": "U ",
        "FREIA1": " ",
        "FREIA2": " "
    },
    {
        "SKU": "COL-10-49309 ",
        "SHOP": "GWIN ",
        "FLDDEF": "Metafield_3 ",
        "PARB": "video ",
        "STAT1": "U ",
        "FREIA1": "19038265573420 ",
        "FREIA2": " "
    },
    {
        "SKU": "COL-10-49000 ",
        "SHOP": "GWEUEN ",
        "FLDDEF": "Metafield_5 ",
        "PARB": "icon_image_1 ",
        "STAT1": " ",
        "FREIA1": "20117934145590 ",
        "FREIA2": " "
    },
    {
        "SKU": "COL-10-49000 ",
        "SHOP": "GWEUDE ",
        "FLDDEF": "Metafield_12 ",
        "PARB": "icon_image_3 ",
        "STAT1": "U ",
        "FREIA1": "13660255846460 ",
        "FREIA2": " "
    },
    {
        "SKU": "COL-10-49000 ",
        "SHOP": "GWEUFR ",
        "FLDDEF": "Metafield_5 ",
        "PARB": "heading ",
        "STAT1": "U ",
        "FREIA1": "18980495228985 ",
        "FREIA2": " "
    },
    {
        "SKU": "COL-10-49309 ",
        "SHOP": "GWEUDE ",
        "FLDDEF": "Metafield_1 ",
        "PARB": "subtitle ",
        "STAT1": "U ",
        "FREIA1": "13672656044092 ",
        "FREIA2": " "
    },
    {
        "SKU": "COL-10-49000 ",
        "SHOP": "GWEUEN ",
        "FLDDEF": "Handle ",
        "PARB": " ",
        "STAT1": " ",
        "FREIA1": "57456984123 ",
        "FREIA2": " "
    },
    {
        "SKU": "COL-10-49309 ",
        "SHOP": "GWIN ",
        "FLDDEF": "Metafield_2 ",
        "PARB": "icon ",
        "STAT1": "U ",
        "FREIA1": "19038265540652 ",
        "FREIA2": " "
    },
    {
        "SKU": "COL-10-49309 ",
        "SHOP": "GWUK ",
        "FLDDEF": "Image_URL ",
        "PARB": " ",
        "STAT1": "U ",
        "FREIA1": " ",
        "FREIA2": " "
    },
    {
        "SKU": "COL-10-49000 ",
        "SHOP": "GWEUDE ",
        "FLDDEF": "Metafield_18 ",
        "PARB": "icon ",
        "STAT1": "U ",
        "FREIA1": "19587379658812 ",
        "FREIA2": " "
    },
    {
        "SKU": "COL-10-49000 ",
        "SHOP": "GWEUEN ",
        "FLDDEF": "Metafield_4 ",
        "PARB": "video ",
        "STAT1": " ",
        "FREIA1": "20117934112822 ",
        "FREIA2": " "
    },
    {
        "SKU": "COL-10-49309 ",
        "SHOP": "GWEUDE ",
        "FLDDEF": "Body_HTML ",
        "PARB": " ",
        "STAT1": "U ",
        "FREIA1": " ",
        "FREIA2": " "
    },
    {
        "SKU": "COL-10-49310 ",
        "SHOP": "GWUK ",
        "FLDDEF": "Handle ",
        "PARB": " ",
        "STAT1": "U ",
        "FREIA1": "261318574141 ",
        "FREIA2": " "
    }
]
```

My goal is to loop through the array and to see where SKU is equal to itself. The goal is to then push all arrays where the SKU is the same into a different multidimensional array.

So for example all the arrays where the SKU = `COL-10-49000` should end up in 1 multidimensional array and all the arrays where the SKU = `COL-10-49310` should end up in 1 multidimensional array.

This is what I currently have, but doesn't seem to be doing the trick

```
foreach($aArray as $a) {
  if($a[SKU] == $a[SKU]) {
        array_push($bArray, $a)
  }
}
```

I am hoping to then have an array which will look like this:

```
[0] => Array( 
  [0] => Array ([SKU] => COL-10-49310 [SHOP] => EU3 [FLDDEF] => Handle [PARB] => [STAT1] => U [FREIA1] => 166926024764 [FREIA2] =>) 
  [1] => Array ([SKU] => COL-10-49310 [SHOP] => EU3 [FLDDEF] => Collection_Title [PARB] => [STAT1] => U [FREIA1] => [FREIA2] =>) 
  [2] => Array ([SKU] => COL-10-49310 [SHOP] => INT1 [FLDDEF] => SEO_1 [PARB] => title_tag [STAT1] => U [FREIA1] => 19034707656748 [FREIA2] => )
) 
[1] => Array([0] => Array ([SKU] => COL-10-49309 [SHOP] => EU3 [FLDDEF] => Handle [PARB] => [STAT1] => U [FREIA1] => 166926024764 [FREIA2] =>) 
  [1] => Array ([SKU] => COL-10-49309 [SHOP] => EU3 [FLDDEF] => Collection_Title [PARB] => [STAT1] => U [FREIA1] => [FREIA2] =>) 
  [2] => Array ([SKU] => COL-10-49309 [SHOP] => INT1 [FLDDEF] => SEO_1 [PARB] => title_tag [STAT1] => U [FREIA1] => 19034707656748 [FREIA2] => ))
```

So each SKU, and all its coresponding arrays will be together in one multidimensional array, where I can then loop through it with a `($i = 0; $i < count($aArray); $i++){}` style.

Comment: "_my hope is that it makes the array easier on the eyes_" For me it doesn't. What have you tried so far, what doesn't work, can you post your code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting. Code-style formatting, with indentation, would make the array a lot easier to read.

Comment: `This is what I currently have`...it seems to be incomplete. How is the constant `SKU` defined? And what does "doesn't seem to be doing the trick" actually mean? Give us a precise description of how the code behaves when you run it (e.g. any errors you see, any unexpected output, etc), not some vague meaningless phrase. Also provide a precise example of the expected output, not just a description. Thanks.

Comment: Also if you're expecting us to use that data to test any code we write, it'll be a _lot_ easier for us to do that if you provide it in a parseable format which we could feed back into a PHP program. e.g. `var_export()` will produce that, and so will `json_encode()`. Make sure you pretty-print it for formatting purposes.

Comment: `if($a[SKU] == $a[SKU])` - how would you expect that to ever _not_ be true?

Comment: You probably want something like `$resultArray = []; foreach($aArray as $a) { $resultArray[$a['SKU']] = $a; }`

Comment: @ADyson are you asking for me to provide a json_encode($array)? Should I post the result of the json_encode() in the question itself? I am a bit new here.

Comment: For the source (nested) array I mean, yes. Either json_encode() or var_export() output is fine. Then we can re-use it in a code example easily because we can decode it back into our program. We can't do that with print_r or var_dump output. Also please show an exact example of the array you're expecting to be produced by your code.

Comment: @ADyson I have now posted the output of the json_encode(pretty_print), I hope that is more helpful

Comment: @Cbroe thank you for your reply, That is in the right direction however, that still leaves different SKU'S in the same array level as each other

Comment: _"however, that still leaves different SKU'S in the same array level as each other"_ - I have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: @Cbroe I have now posted and expanded on the format of the array I would like back hopefully that makes my goals clearer. With your suggestion I recieve an array where SKU's with different values are on the same index level

Comment: Is the question so poorly formulated? :o

Comment: So basically you want to split the data into separate arrays, with each array containing only the entries relating to a single SKU

Comment: Yes, the array should be split up into seperate arrays with the SKU being the decider :) thank you, that is a very concise way of putting it

Comment: Do the arrays have to be numeric-indexed in the top-level? It would be easier to solve the problem if they could be associative arrays, with the SKU as the key.

Comment: No they do not have to be numeric-indexed, the SKU can be used as the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to split the data into separate arrays, with each array containing only the entries relating to a single SKU.

As you mentioned in the comments that the top-level array can be indexed associatively rather than numerically, this makes it quite trivial to allocate items to each sub-array by reading the SKU from the item.

e.g.

```
$output = array();

foreach ($input as $item)
{
    $sku = $item["SKU"];
    $output[$sku][] = $item;
}
```

Live demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/770b4fcc096449ee6c0a9fd39174f5b6bcd4106a

Comment: Thanks for the answer ADyson, if you'll bear with me just a moment, as I wrap my head around this.

What you are doing is:
1. assigning the SKU to a variable.
2. pushing into a new array with the SKU as key.

I have a question, how does the ´´´ $output[$sku][] = $item ´´´  know to push only the arrays with the same SKU?

Comment: `how does the ´´´ $output[$sku][] = $item ´´´ know to push only the arrays with the same SKU`...well it doesn't, at least not in the sense you're probably thinking of. Look at it this way: In $output there's already an array whose key corresponds to the SKU (or if there isn't, that line of code will create one as it goes along). So all it's saying is "find the entry in $output whose SKU matches the SKU of the current input item, and add the item to it". That's why using the SKU as an index value makes this super-simple to implement.

Comment: crazy, I guess the lack of an IF statement is confusing me in terms of it being able to match the SKU in $output to the $item. 

Thank you for your explanation too

Comment: You don't need to compare anything with `if` - instead it's a simple assignment. Imagine if it was hard-coded instead e.g. `$output["COL-10-49310"][] = $item;` - that would always assign the item to the same SKU array, but hopefully you see the point that it's just placing it directly in the array entry which matches that code. (And if there isn't yet a matching code in the array, it will automatically create one first).

Comment: OK, yes that hardcoded example makes more sense thank you

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering but I just need to clarify it for my brain XD .

So: its looping through, creating when necessary a new `$output['COL-SKU']` Key  and on each loop, its assigning to that key the values where it can find a match between the value and key? and it keeps going until it has no more matching keys left, and then creates a new key, and repeats the process

Comment: `on each loop, its assigning to that key the values where it can find a match between the value and key? and it keeps going until it has no more matching keys left, and then creates a new key, and repeats the process `...no, not really, I don't think. It just loops through the input array _once_. Each time it loops, it looks at the SKU of the current input item. It then puts that input item into the right sub-array in the output, simply by using the input SKU to refer to the correct sub-array directly.

Comment: Let's use an analogy and pretend you're doing this by hand. You have some items coming off a conveyor belt, one by one. Each item has a label attached, showing a number. At the end of the conveyor belt, you have some baskets. Each basket has a number. So you simply pick up each item as it comes to you, look at the number on the label, and put it in the basket which has the same number. (If there isn't a basket with that number, you get another basket from your pile, number it, and then proceed as before.). There's no comparing to others, no repeating. Just a simple one-by-one process

Comment: Great thanks for that analogy, so trying to take this further, the `$item['SKU']` is the label written on the items coming off the conveyor belt so if I were to change the label to `$item['SHOP']`, that would then be the defining label written on the item, meaning the items would be sorted into boxes based off of that, not the `$item['SKU']` ? I guess my question being here : the position of the key in the array is irrelevant, its only looking at the key of the array, as defined by `$item['EXAMPLE']`?

Comment: `if I were to change the label to $item['SHOP'], that would then be the defining label written on the item, meaning the items would be sorted into boxes based off of that, not the $item['SKU']`....exactly, yes. It's a trival change - here's a demo of it doing exactly that: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/edf42ab6a97c61331645ef75dbae16fb4785ca18 . And yes, the position in the array is not relevant.

Answer (score 2):

So according to your question I can provide you this solution:

1. Decode json

   `$data = json_decode(<your_json_string>)`
2. Then we can use [`array_reduce()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-reduce.php) function to get result array.

```
$result = array_reduce($data, function (array $accumulator, $item) {
    $accumulator[$item->SKU][] = $item;

    return $accumulator;
}, []);
```

So `$result` array will contain to dimensional array with each SKU value key

Comment: Dear moder code style button do not work

Comment: This is hugely over-complicated, and anyway it doesn't produce the requested output - demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/83e75adb98c94c56edb695efa94af90cce5097bb

Comment: dear ADyson i am not your employee and my goal is to give you idea solving your problem, and it does. Just make your edits of my code to reach your goal. It's easy. So i will be happy if you will try yourself at first. If it doesnt workout. I will help you more, but latter.

Comment: It's not _my_ problem - I didn't ask the question :-). I'm simply trying to advise you that your post doesn't answer the OP's question, and you may want to think about modifying it, if you wish to get more votes. If you notice, I already posted a working answer which has been accepted. I merely wanted to point out that yours could be improved. The goal of an answer should be to solve the problem, not merely to give an idea. And I don't think this provides an idea anyway - the output of your code is so completely different than what was requested, it cannot really be modified easily by the OP.

Comment: oh sory, it seems i did not understand task correctly. answer updated